# Cloudfront / S3 Bucket with W3TC

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a setup with Amazon Cloudfront / S3 and Wordpress W3TC. Bucket has no ACL or Read-Settings for the public but a policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1502130814505",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1502130814505",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxx/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

In IAM the user has full Cloudfront- and S3Access.

In Cloudfront the Origin is not restricted by a user.

Connection with W3TC works fine. Using so far only the Cloudfront URL. Uploading media etc with no problem.

But the Cloudfront-URL gives only

`AccessDenied`

So the Wordpress-Site cannot fetch any media, Styles or Themefiles from Cloudfrount.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable SSL on your WP site?

Comment: Yes. The Site itself serves via LetsEncrypt. The Behaviour in Cloudfront is on HTTP and HTTPS (default).

Comment: It works now. After playing around, getting almost crazy and finally uploading the files with awsCLI and  -not- the W3TC-povided uploader it works perfect.

Comment: @HolgerBartels what was the solution after your playing around? is it just uploading files with awscli instead of the other one?

Comment: @nxmohamad, thank you for your question. I had to completely delete the bucket, create a new one and copy the files via aws-cli.